# TCP spring integration - request-ack-confirm

Tags: tcpclient, spring-integration-ip

I have to write a client app, which will send over tcp, a request to a non Spring application, receive a response, verify it and if it is valid, should return an ok message to the server.
The payload is byte array. This flow will be scheduled to run on some intervals.

I tried with TcpOutboundGateway and manage to send and receive the payload, but when the client returns the ok massage i get Timeout exception, because the gateway expects an answer, which the server will not send.
I thought about collaboration inbound and outbound channel adapters but if i am getting the idea right, this will not do, as the server is out of my control and it can't populate the ip_connectionId.

Any ideas how to solve my app requirements.